# Несколько AsyncTask для парсинга страницы?

Tags: java, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Вопрос в следующем, у меня есть asynctask, в котором я копирую с некой интернет-страницы текст при нажатии на кнопку, но также мне нужно парсить другую страницу при нажатии на вторую кнопку, как в таком случае поступают? спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае `AsyncTask` вам нужно создать новый экземпляр задачи и запустить её. Т.е. использовать уже завершённую задачу заново не нужно и даже не получится.

Также попробуйте более современные и модные способы общения с сетью. Например связку `OkHttp`, `RxJava` и `Retrolambda`. С ними получение HTML страницы это всего 4 строки:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> new OkHttpClient.Builder().build().newCall(new Request.Builder().url("https://kremlin.ru").build()).execute().body().string())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(response -> Log.d("html: " + response ), error -> Log.e("error", e));
```

Код выше скачивает вне основного потока HTML с сайта и выводит его в консоль уже в основном потоке. В случае ошибки она также будет выведена в консоль. В этом же стиле можно и парсинг станицы делать.

Comment: у меня по нажатию на первую кнопку происходит авторизация в asynctask, а потом по второй кнопке я должен получить текст

Comment: @SWR, этот ваш комментарий не несёт в себе информации полезно дополняющей вопрос. Подозреваю, что вы не увидели в ответе ответа на ваш вопрос. Возможно это вызвано расплывчатостью формулировки. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. В данный момент не очень понятно что у вас за проблема.

Comment: у меня 2 задачи: первая - это авторизоваться по кнопке, вторая - это спарсить текст при нажатии на кнопку с другой страницы, не понимаю каким образом создать 2 asynctask (задачи же разные будут в doitbackground)? я пытаюсь сделать сейчас так: первая задача у меня в asynctask, а вторую я реализовываю через thread, используя runnable

Comment: @SWR, вы можете просто создать два разных класса-наследника `AsyncTask` - в них будут свои реализации методов. И соответственно вызывать нужный в нужном месте

Comment: так и сделал, спасибо) а как дождаться окончания выполнения asynctask? чтобы когда нажимаешь на кнопку потоки не плодились кучей

Comment: @SWR, можно, например, вызывать `button.setEnable(false)` а после, в методе `onPostExecute()` таски обратно её включить  `button.setEnable(true)`

Comment: спасибо большое